# i want to update to completed a SharePoint item when another SharePoint has been modified to completed with Power Automate

Tags: workflow, power-automate

I have tried to do this for over a month now but just cant seem to get it right.

I send over information to a SharePoint that someone else works and once it is completed they change the status of it to completed. once that is done search on my SharePoint where the requestor submitted their request and have to mark it completed so they know it has. i want to create a flow that when marked in SharePoint 1 completed it is also marked in my SharePoint completed with out having to go in and look for it.

the first image is the SharePoint where i submit the information. the second image is my SharePoint. SOL ID is the ID of the SharePoint that is worked by someone else where i place the number i get when submitting an item so i can find it quicker in my SharePoint.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm a PowerApps newbie, but I did successfully update a list based on a change made in another list. Here's what I did.

Example: When the [ID] field of list A changes, update the [SOL ID] field of list B as well.

1-In your list A SharePoint settings, make sure that there is a lookup field that targets List B and includes the List B ID field (it can either be the primary field or one of the secondary fields added using the checkboxes). That needs to be there for PowerApps to see it in your flow.

2-In your PowerApps flow, do this:
Trigger: When an item changes (specify site/list A)
Action: Update an item (specify the site/list B)
Click into the [SOL ID] field, then click the "add dynamic content" link that pops up.
Find and select the Dynamic Content field from List A called "ID".

---

This should enable you to update the List B [SOL ID] field with the value of the List A [ID] field.

Did that work? Please report back!